# Split wildcard tag into wildcard-text and bounded-wildcard

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, retag-request

There is a [wildcard](/questions/tagged/wildcard) tag that is (presently) described as applying to the text matching context.  However, many Java generics questions are incorrectly tagged with this.  I recently created a [bounded-wildcard](/questions/tagged/bounded-wildcard) tag with appropriate description, and started to re-tag many (appropriate) questions with it.

However, I quickly realized that this will be a painful effort.  If some administrator has the ability to search questions for the text "bounded wildcard" in a question and from each question about Java bounded wildcards, remove the "wildcard" tag and replace it with "bounded-wildcard".  That would be great and would probably be 95-99% accurate.  Even better, he or she could eyeball the questions themselves.

Also, it would be great if someone would rename the wildcard tag to wildcard-text and prevent the wildcard tag from being created.

Comment: Alas, our tools are not nearly that sophisticated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So I guess I need to write a meta-meta support question to ask Jeff or someone to write a tool that will either do search-based operations or at minimum pasting a list of URLs/browser extension so we can use google/cut-and-paste to help?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be that many.  I did a search for "Bounded Wildcard" and got 67 hits, but a lot of them aren't really applicable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22bounded+wildcard%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=site:stackoverflow.com+%22bounded+wildcard%22&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=zSn&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&prmd=imvns&ei=mRt1T83dBIjfgQfti82FDw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f23c61bd7e89fd45&biw=1275&bih=849) reports 1,300.  The first 30 or so were all applicable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I saw that you edited a few yourself, thanks.  Is it possible to deprecate the ambiguous wildcard tag and prevent new tags from being applied?

Comment: That's a dev-only option, and I'm not convinced [wildcard] is a useless tag.

Comment: Are [all of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwildcard%5D+java+generics) bounded wildcards?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Given that if you accept the tag wiki's definition, [over half the questions are incorrectly applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildcard), there's clearly a problem.  People apparently don't seem to take the time to read the tag wiki as they enter it.  If the tag were disallowed, then they would be forced to chose the more specific correct tag.

Comment: Tags *can* have more than one meaning, y'know.  If you really want the java generic specific ones, couldn't you just search for [java] [generic] [wildcard]?

Comment: @RobertHarvey re: "Are all of these bounded wildcards?" spot checking--about 80% of them are specifically bounded wildcards, the others are unbounded wildcards.  Though none that I saw were about text wildcards.

Comment: @RobertHarvey then the tag wiki should be edited to reflect this.  I'm not sure this is a good practice to encourage.  It would be one thing if they were related, but there's little in common between text-wildcard and Java generic wildcards.  Is it possible to subscribe to "[java]+[generic]+[wildcard]"?

Comment: No, but that's the *only* thing that a multiple tag tuple is not capable of.  Do people really subscribe to these things?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe they would if only they could just get notified of topics they were interested in, and not text wildcards?  :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I assume we're talking about tag filters right?  I just tested this and the tag filters do a union, not an intersection.  Is there a way to search for "[java]+[generic]+[wildcard]"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+generics+wildcard

Comment: Oh, that's great--and there's an RSS feed available.  Good enough for government work, thanks!