# When cleaning up tags, please use one post per tag so that real community input can be given

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, per-site-meta

*Please Don't Let This Happen To Your Site*

A recent problem surfaced on [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-october-2013), where they have one question that they use for tag burnination/cleanup, and they just edit the question every month to a new burn order.  This has led to a large amount of upvotes on the post, that are usually not relevant to the new tag edited in.  This gives the illusion of community consensus on the new cleanup request, just the illusion.  While it is probably too late for Super User to get past that agenda, and they will just lose a lot of useful tags, I would make a plea to the other Meta mods out there:

**Please use one post per tag, or succinct group of tags, so that real community input can be given.**

Note:  I put the example in here, because I knew that if I didn't everyone would bug me for it.  As expected, it has drawn quite a few answers not related to the general point of this post, only to the specific instance.  Darned if you do, darned if you don't.  Thank you to those who posted answers relative to the point of the discussion.

Comment: I guess most of these edits could be very well reverted as "radical change" ;)

Comment: @Yannis, I thought the first title was catchy, but will bow to your wisdom.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It was catchy, but it didn't really describe the issue and wasn't really search friendly. Also, when I first read the title I thought this would be exciting, and was very disappointed when it turned out to be about tag cleanups... ;)

Comment: I get excited by tag cleanups :)

Comment: Why is this on MSO? This is a MSU issue. MSO doesn't tell other sites how to run their community. Other sites -- often for very good reason -- deliberately have different policies than SO. This is intended and expected by SE. All it seems you're doing here is trying to attract attention and shame the SU mods, but your viewpoint is invalid to begin with, because it's based on the false assumption that the post you're referring to is edited without community consensus, when in fact, community consensus is raised in separate questions before the tags are moved to that post.

Comment: @allquixotic, __this is to address all meta-site mods/users__.  The problem just surfaced on SU.  See my comments on Oliver's answer relative to the other question.

Comment: Lance, this [Rollback War](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/7299/revisions) was not needed.

Comment: @dcaswell, no, the editing out of what the moderator disagreed with (instead of just downvoting) was what was not needed.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Is this a policy that can or should be applied to *all meta-sites*? You seem to have assumed "Yes", without stopping to actually ask the question (which is what this question seems to try to ask, if you'd let it).

Comment: @DarthAndroid, yes, I think all Meta sites should be very careful about their tag cleanups.  I'm involved in a few, and am concerned about the tagging on all of them.  __Good tagging is critical to good searching.__

Comment: @dcaswell - wow, "Nazi thing"?  Way to Godwin a thread, Lance

Comment: @DarthAndroid I actually thought this was an official announcement rather than a (quite sensible) suggestion

Comment: @RichardTingle That is my point; The underlying question / suggestion is quite valid and a good discussion to have, but the phrasing of the title and rhetoric being used by the author is drowning it out.

Comment: The note you've added to the end of your question is just as irrelevant as the answers you're calling out in it.  I'd remove it, but I feel like you would probably roll it back.  The warning at the beginning of your post is just fluff, taking up room in the question preview (it's also title-cased for no reason, which makes me cringe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This has happened before on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) (10k only, thankfully), and it was a mess. A huge, prolonged mess with 85 answers, plus tags that were edited directly into the question. We ended up with tags deleted just because someone edited them in, with absolutely no oversight. [I raised my own <s>rant</s>question about it back then.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134390/who-decides-whether-a-tag-gets-cleaned-up-and-how)

Yes, indeed, tag cleanups should be done with one thread per tag, or per group or closely-related tag.

(I am purposefully ignoring the specific tag that led to this meta question. Regardless of any nastiness surrounding the debate about that particular tag, this meta question is a valid issue in its own right.)

Comment: You also should make a note of the "size" of the site, which is also important on this matters; and the sentiment of the users of the sites ;)

Comment: Is this intended as advice for Stack Overflow, or all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @AdamRackis All Stack Exchange sites. SO was just an example, undoubtedly unequaled when it comes to scale, and the only catastrophic monster thread that I can rembember offhand, but I'd be surprised if it hadn't happened anywhere else.

Comment: @Gilles - are you not convinced by some of the other posts that other, smaller sites have had good experience using a different approach?

Comment: @AdamRackis Example? I only see that [gamedev](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/155) has been cited in this thread. I can't judge as a complete outsider, but the accumulation of answers does make it hard to see what is long-done, what is still being debated, what is consensual and what isn't. Oh, and I just remembered [travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/61). That question is from the private beta, when it could actually make sense, but it should have been retired after that, though fortunately the recent answers are all about minor things.

Comment: @Gilles - well mainly the SU mods defending their current system as effective.  It seems as though this is working well for them, Lance being unhappy notwithstanding.  Though obviously I agree with you this approach probably wouldn't work for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14):

We already have what you are referring to. The decision to remove [configuration](/questions/tagged/configuration) was reached in a previous question: [Merge connection & configuration related tags](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6320/merge-connection-configuration-related-tags) The fact that a decision has been reached is indicated by the question being upvoted and noone disagreeing with the suggestion.

The question you linked above is just used to maintain a list of tags for which a consensus has already been reached.

Besides that fact, you chose to post an answer to this thread and you received community input on it. The input was downvotes. Indicating that the community does not agree with you.

In addition to that, you chose to behave yourself extremely poorly to the point where I had to lock your answer.

Comment: You not only locked my answer because you disagreed with it, you edited out half of it.  You have your agenda and it's obviously not the health of the Super User site or its community.

Comment: There was no decision reached in the question you linked to.  In fact, your answer (_the only answer_) there shows `configuration` as __`status_deferred`__.  And 5 net upvotes does not community consensus make.

Comment: "And 5 net upvotes does not community consensus make" -- Maybe not on MSO, but the MSU community is much, MUCH smaller. How many upvotes does it take? Hmm? What about a 6 month old niche site that recently left beta? How many upvotes do they need? Does every single site have to have as many upvotes as SO/MSO to establish community consensus? And how long do we have to wait for dissenting opinions until we can be sure we have consensus? These topics are worth discussing, but you seem to be applying your own normative assumption here that 5 upvotes is definitely not enough *ever* and I disagree.

Comment: If you want to bring up the topic of how many upvotes / how long of a time period is required in order to firmly establish community consensus on MSU, please, feel free. That's a perfectly valid question, and assuming it doesn't come with a pre-loaded agenda, I'd even upvote it.

Comment: I'm not on SU that often, but `You have your agenda and it's obviously not the health of the Super User site or its community` is a fairly bold accusation to make.

Comment: There's another problem with looking at several-months-old posts and counting votes on it - votes can change *in either direction* with time. [In May](http://web.archive.org/web/20130510183050/http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6320/merge-connection-configuration-related-tags), said question and answer had one more upvote than they do now. I suspect the downvotes were actually added today.

Comment: @LBT yup, especially when directed to an _elected_ moderator.

Comment: @Bob, agreed, 6 before today.

Comment: @Bob look for the timeline that is in my answer below, you can count them :P

Comment: @LanceRoberts: I reverted to a previous revision of your answer because you insisted on having a nazi reference in it, which was not welcome. This should have been clear to you from the initial edit to your answer. The fact that part of your answer was lost in the process is simply due to the fact that you seemed very uncooperative and I simply rolled back instead of editing your answer to accommodate for your most recent additions to it. The lost content wasn't in the proper context to begin with. The proper context is a question like this one. Which you posted now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you handled this one right and Lance did not behave appropriately. Nonetheless, Lance's admonition here is a valid one. Tag cleanups should not be done in one huge thread. Please don't mix up the two issues.

Comment: @Gilles: Participation on cleanups, initiated through questions concerning themselves with single or small groups of tags, is usually very low. Participation on judging the quality of said tags is well though. The cleanup job is usually left to the moderators of the site. This has the undesirable outcome of creating a huge workload for said moderators. The path that was chosen on SU allows us to share the workload with the community and the outcome is as desired (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg With a monster thread, you get a lot of cumulated attention on the monster thread, but less attention on individual tags. If a topic thread has concluded that a tag should be removed and you want to set the community at it, a monster thread is fine — just don't use it for decisions, use it only to spread the word about what has been decided.

Comment: @Gilles: That is exactly what we are doing right now. I assumed you were implying that we aren't.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You don't seem to be doing that (unless there's some other thread that should be linked but isn't). The [monster thread](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-october-2013) justifies `configuration` as a tag to be removed because of http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6320/merge-connection-configuration-related-tags which does not come to that conclusion.

Comment: @Gilles: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6320/merge-connection-configuration-related-tags does come to the conclusion as there are a positive amount of votes remaining on the question and nobody has ever disagreed with the proposal. On SU this is sufficient to make a decision.

Answer (score 12):

Its not a problem - we've been doing it this way through many cycles of tag clearups, and having a centralised, community moderated and maintained list is a much more efficient way of doing so.

Considering the sheer amount of crappy tags we wade through, especially considering we try to avoid flooding the front page, this would cause un-necessary work (since we need to search for, and then act on these questions). Having questions that request retagging, then having a consolidated list is just common sense.

While we're all part of one big happy SE family, *we all do things in different ways cause our needs are different*. You've walked into meta.su, and *insisted* we do things your way, then complained when we disagreed - using words like "nazi".

This is a little like complaining that our pantry isn't in alphabetical order, then complaining to the cops when we refused to rearrange things. This is just silly.

Comment: No, I didn't walk into SU, I've got 4.5k there.  And I only insisted you do things the right way, not just having mods tyrannically implement their will.

Comment: "The right way" - see, thats a problem here. I'm not saying *everyone* needs to do it our way. I'm saying this is a system that we have used, and works VERY well for our needs. I've explained how and why we use it. Your arguement is nothing more than "Its the right way, and the mods are wrong cause they disagree with me". If I have a sleepless night, and want to fix some tags cause the sheep are off on vacation, I know *exactly* were to look. Having a bunch of questions per tags means you never know where to look. It makes more sense to have the mustard next to the ketchup, not the marmalade.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I have to raise a few things. Firstly, what you consider the Right Way (TM) may not be what others consider right - the very issue you are complaining against! And can we *please not* resort to deliberately inflammatory statements like "tyranically implement their will"? That does nothing to help your argument.

Comment: @LanceRoberts One more piece of advice to add to Bob's and JMan's: Just because you seem to be the only SU user currently having a dispute with this particular practice, that doesn't mean that you need to use such extreme hyperbole and strong language in your rhetoric. Using terms like "tyrannical" and "Nazi" *weakens* your position and prevents others from taking you seriously. Please make constructive criticism by offering ways that the site can be improved, rather than comparing well-intentioned, devoted users of SU to dystopian governments in unfounded ad-hominem attacks.

Comment: I assure you that if your points are well-reasoned, and if you are patient, logical, and distance your personal feelings from the subject matter at hand, that your opinion will be heard, and we (the diamond mods and other site participants) will do our best to help satisfy your request, or at least come to some sort of compromise. There's no need to dramatize the subject; that only makes things worse.

Comment: @allquixotic, I've never understood why people don't want to hear the truth, but in this day and age I'm sure you're correct.  Everyone wants to put their head in the sand and wish away the problems.

Comment: @LanceRoberts how is calling someone a nazi "the truth"? This is just your own position expressed both offensively and aggressively. We have all given you various reasons why "configuration" is a classic meta tag. Where do you come off equating your opinion with "the truth"?

Comment: @terdon, no, there were no reasons given, just an order.

Comment: @LanceRoberts there was no order, as others have already told you, this was a community decision. I don't think you understand what meta tags are, I linked you to the relevant [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). How is "configuration" not a meta tag?

Comment: The truth? Anyone can look at the edit trail, and decide for themselves whether your actions and the edits were necessary. I feel there's a clear unfamiliarity with the processes that SU regulars use on the site, and an attempt to impose standards upon us, unilaterally, by demanding that we do things *your* way. In your original post, there is no reasons given, just a demand, backed up by neither positional, nor moral power of any sort. This seems to be an attempt to impose your views on SU as a whole, and I don't really think its acceptable.

Comment: @LanceRoberts instead of just entrench yourself in that position look for facts that say that you are telling the truth and everyone else is wrong...

Comment: @terdon, by the way, you didn't read the source before edit close enough, I didn't call anyone anything.  I described a behavior that was going on.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, lots of people today think that passivity is the way to go, but I refuse to accede to that belief.  I will do what's right regardless of the opposition of the powers that be.  The mods who ordered the tag cut are the ones who imposed their views on SU.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I read it perfectly well. You wrote, and I quote, "Please stop the Nazi thing". Apparently, people who don't agree with your personal choices are acting like Nazis. In fact, there is a word (several) for people who assume everyone who doesn't share their opinion is wrong but I will refrain from using it. As you should have done in the first place.

Comment: @terdon, then you shouldn't have misstated what I said in the earlier comment.  I attacked behavior, not people.  SU should follow the golden rule, not the rule of the elite.

Comment: @LanceRoberts we are, you're not. Look around you, the community disagrees with you. You have yet to explain why you think that the tag in question does not fall under the category of meta tags as defined in the blog post I will not link to a 3rd time. You also seem reluctant to accept that Nazi is not a word to be thrown around that easily. If you had posted an honest, polite question explaining your views, we'd be fine with it. Instead, you just resorted to name-calling and aggression.

Comment: @terdon, you don't need to lie about things.  I posted plenty of reasons, one in the answer, and more in the comments (if they haven't been deleted yet).  What you mean by 'polite' is 'passive'.

Comment: @LanceRoberts polite is not using a word that people find offensive. I am not lying about anything. Where does that come from? I personally find the tag useless and a perfect example of a meta tag. In fact, it is pretty much the definition of a meta tag. Your post simply shows that you have not understood what meta tags are. In any case, the votes and reactions clearly show that you are in a minority of one on this so stop being so aggressive about it and back off.

Comment: @terdon, your lie was 'You have yet to explain why you think that the tag in question does not fall...'.  It can't possibly be a meta tag, because it is exactly and specifically what the questions are about (if tagged properly).

Comment: Thats an opinion. Not everyone who disagrees with you is lying. I share that opnion with terdon, that you have not made a compelling argument for your case, that the tag deletion was by fiat.

Comment: @LanceRoberts "The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or **generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.)**." That is a meta tag. We want tags that are useful for searching, about 76% of questions on SU are about configuring something or other, that tag adds nothing useful. You seem to want to impose _your_ opinion on everyone, how is that not exactly the behavior you are complaining about?

Comment: @terdon, please don't confuse facts with opinion.  It's a fact that configuration is the topic of the question, so (to repeat what I already said elsewhere that you an JG are denying I said) when I want to search 'excel' and 'configuration', I won't get questions tagged with 'worksheet-function' (except coincidentally).  Configuration is a specific function that is addressed a lot of SU (as you pointed out) and needs to be able to be searched on by tag.  I wasn't the one unilaterally deleting tags, so I was not imposing my will on anyone.  I just pointed out the truth.

Comment: @LanceRoberts It is a fact that "Configuration" fits the definition of meta tags perfectly. It is also a fact that no one was doing anything unilaterally, in fact, the only one trying to impose a personal choice here is you. You seem to be of the "I have made up my mind, please don't confuse me with facts" brigade and have no interest in engaging in a constructive conversation.

Comment: @terdon, so ad-hominem is your only argument.

Comment: @LanceRoberts The problem is that 'configuration' is not specific at all. Configuring Excel via Options is wildly different from configuring the `/etc/hosts` file on linux is wildly different from configuring a printer on OS X. *A tag should be specific and concrete by itself*, and `Configuration` is neither; It only has meaning when given context by another tag. It's like tagging every question on SU with `Computers`: The tag would not have one concrete meaning, it would have a slightly different meaning with every post that uses it.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, it would have a slightly different _context_, but the _meaning_ would be the same.

Comment: @LanceRoberts _ad nauseam_ seems to be your only argument.

Comment: Exactly, the comments are no place for extensive discussions, especially not if they don't yield an improvement in the question and/or answer; people have voted and the results are clear, any further discussion here will thus not lead to any useful results and will waste your time. As someone who has and hasn't been here for a long time, if you are being the only one really caring about the removal of a single tag where all others vote different and oppose it is really not worth it and it will yield you no gain...

Comment: @terdon Configuration is not a classic meta tag. [Here's](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) a description of meta tags. If Configuration is describing the content of a question then it's not a meta-tag.

Comment: @dcaswell it is a meta tag because it falls into the definition (from that blog post) that I quoted above. It gives no info on what is being asked or what the question it is about, it just defines the _type_ of question and not it's content. "foo-configuration" is not a meta tag, "configuration" alone is.

Comment: @terdon And you're wrong. What Jeff gives as an example of who is doing this right is the cooking site. And they have a frying tag that goes along with what's being fried: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frying In the same way there's a configuration tag that goes along with what's being configured. There's no frying fish tag, there's two separate tags.

Comment: @dcaswell but each SE site behaves different, if we go by what you say >50% of the questions will have this tag because most of questions is about configure some piece of software.

Comment: @dcaswell how is that even relevant? Frying directly implies using a frying pan to prepare food. It is informative. Different sites have different scopes and configuration is just too general to be anything but a meta tag on SU. Configuring what? How? In what OS? Or do you maybe mean configure scripts? Or configuring ports? Or configuration options for software? See what I mean? It is about as useful as a "cooking" tag on cooking.se.

Comment: @terdon It may not be useful. But it's not a meta-tag. And now you're switching arguments in mid-stream to an argument that it's common without proving that common tags are wrong.

Comment: @dcaswell you misunderstand. It is a meta tag because it is a tag  "that doesn’t say anything by itself – you can’t tell what the question is about unless it is paired with some other tag (or several of them)." that is a direct (well, changing _they_ to _it_) from the blog post on meta tags and the configuration tag fits it perfectly. I never said it was _common_ my argument is that it is not informative. My second, and more important, argument is that this is a community opinion not just mine and it has not been imposed but reached by consensus a year ago.

Comment: @terdon Certainly it says something by itself. In the same way that we have Algorithm on Stackoverflow, Baking on Cooking, or Discussion on this site.

Comment: @dcaswell discussion is in it self a meta-tag by definition

Comment: @braiam You don't sound like you care about the issue at all. You'd be a lot more persuasive if you were able to create a post that didn't redefine [common words](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/434/20381) to justify your actions. p.s. You're wrong again about the meaning of "meta-tag". A meta tag is a tag that does not describe the content of a question.

Comment: @dcaswell care to illustrate me why [meta-tag:discussion] is not a meta-tag?

Comment: @braiam Because the content of the question is about having a discussion. Meta tags are tags that are NOT ABOUT CONTENT.

Comment: @dcaswell Perhaps this is just a difference between the SE sites, but on SU we seem to interpret "does not describe the content of a question" to mean "tags which do not tell you anything useful about the content of a question". Arguably a "Computers" tag does tell you *something* about a question on SU, but it is not in any way useful to the purpose of tagging, and I would expect it to be removed under the premise of "too-broad meta-tag". More specifically, if a tag does not effectively narrow down the knowledge domain that might be required to answer the question, I consider it a "meta-tag"

Comment: @dcaswell please, then put the tag `discussion` in a question about `discussion` in any of the main sites of SE, and lets see how it goes. BTW, the syntax to get that link was `[meta-tag:discussion]` and defines *any kind of discussion* which without `tags` `retagging`, `other-tag` doesn't say anything about the question specific points but an overlay broad description of the question. ;)

Comment: @dcaswell please post a question on SU's meta and we can discuss this there where it belongs.

Comment: @terdon I'm clear on the meaning of the word meta. If you're still confused feel free to ask. if someone is trying to figure out how to configure something then Configuration is not a meta-tag. If it is a bad tag then someone ought to be able to describe why without redefining words.

Comment: @dcaswell please don't continue this issue here, post a question on SU's meta and we can discuss it properly in a venue that allows the community to vote.

Comment: @terdon I don't have any urge to go post on your meta. I went and visited your meta and someone was getting down-voted, and argued with by Moderators through comments, for suggesting that people know about the topic before they they answer a question. The very last thing I need is a group where people are googling on my behalf.

Answer (score 12):

I've given this advice in private with regards to a different sort of thing, but it can't hurt to have public statement.

There are multiple approaches to these kinds of jobs. Super User's monthly updating thread, collected both directly and by other threads, is one example. On Game Development, [they have a single thread as well](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread), but each tag or group of tags is collected in answers rather than any separate questions. Other sites use whole questions for each tag or group of related tags, which can be demonstrably seen throughout a lot of Meta Stack Overflow.

We don't have a universal requirement for how these progress, though we do offer guidelines. Each approach has its own merits. When a tag/set-of-related-tags gets its own question, then you have larger room for discussion and coordination for complex or controversial jobs. When you have a sort of "master" question, it's more organized and traceable and is very streamlined for communities that are in tune with one another.

**What is important is what works for the given community.** This not only applies to these kind of cleanup organizations, but the very system of tagging itself is to varying degrees community-specific. Different communities can, and will, take their own approaches to what constitutes good tagging for them, and by consequence what is good searching. On [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net), they use a very unique prefix system that may seem a bit unusual to an SE veteran, but to those on MO it is an exceptionally helpful tool that smooths their experience and shapes their search culture. On [Arqade](http://arqade.com), most questions get no more than one tag, instead resulting in most specific searches being textual rather than tag-based. What works for one site doesn't necessarily work for the network general standard, and vice versa.

Personally? I typically recommend hosting separate questions for each one, in the same way that retag requests are traditionally handled. But that doesn't work for everyone, and for this, each site has its own strategies. And I feel that these strategies should be respected.

Comment: Should a community decides this through consensus (voting) on its meta? Or should "however it works now" be what's respected?

Comment: @dcaswell the communities _do_ decide this on their meta. This issue was resolved in a perfectly democratic way on our (SU) meta. It is only the OP who disagrees as far as I can tell.

Comment: @dcaswell Going by numbers alone is not always the best way to approach these, both in terms of what makes consensus and what makes solid choices. Nor should "status quo" be thought indestructible. If the current approach has flaws that people feel are ruining the community then it would be reasonable to speak up against it. And if they get what feels to be either a lot of support or a lot of pushback, that then sorta says how people feel.

Answer (score 8):

[The configuration tag was added in Feb 26 by tempy.](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/fc54c92f-847a-47e0-be5f-3c3df17bea9f/view-source) Since that time the question received 23 net upvotes [as seen in the timeline](http://meta.superuser.com/posts/5718/timeline). It was not a mod that said that the tag has to go, but a user, and the community also expressed their approval in upvotes.